# asp.net httpClient sending json not working

Tags: asp.net, httpclient

I would like t send data from one of my asp.net application to another. I'm trying to do it using HttpClient.

My First application:

```
public class PostVacanciesController : Controller
{
    public myEntity db = new myEntity();
    public const string sendAppURL = "http://localhost:51394/SecondApp/sendData";

    public ActionResult PostTest()
    {
        try
        {
            PostData dataPost = new PostData();

            // Some code to get PostData from database

            var myContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataPost);
            var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myContent);
            var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
            byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(sendAppURL);
            var result = client.PostAsync("", byteContent).Result;

            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        } catch(Exception any)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }
    }
}
```

My PostData model:

```
public class PostData
{
    public int PropertyID { get; set; }
    public List<int> Units { get; set; } = null;
}
```

Here is my second application here I try to get the data

```
public class SecondAppController : Controller
{

    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public ActionResult sendData(FeedData receiveData)
    { 
        // receiveData variable is wrong.
        // It is showing PropertyID = 0 and Units = null

        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

My FeedData model:

```
public class FeedData
{
    public int PropertyID { get; set; }
    public List<int> Units { get; set; } = null;
}
```

Does anyone know why it is not sending the data? If I create a break point before calling the second App, I can see that it has data to send.

Thanks

Comment: Side note, why do you initialize your `List<int>` to `null`? That's redundant because `null` is the default value for all objects.

Comment: Why using `ByteArrayContent` and not `StringContent`?

Comment: Guys... I start started using asp.net, so my code might be not correct. However, I am not getting any error, just the data is not being sent

Comment: @MaxBoy confirm which version of asp.net mvc you are using for both projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update action to use `StringContent` as you are already serializing the JSON string.

```
public const string sendAppURL = "http://localhost:51394/SecondApp/sendData";
static HttpClient client = new HttpClient() {
    BaseAddress = new Uri(sendAppURL)
};

public async Task<ActionResult> PostTest() {
    try {
        PostData dataPost = new PostData();

        // Some code to get PostData from database

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataPost);
        var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = await client.PostAsync("", content);

        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(response.StatusCode);
    } catch(Exception any) {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
    }
}
```

Note the inclusion of the async syntax.

You need to verify which `HttpPost` attribute you are using as the second controller has `[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]` while it inherits from `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` which uses the `[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]`